# Can´t add less-compiler lessc on Netbeans 7.4

Tags: netbeans, less

At first I downloaded Less from GitHub and saved the folder on my disk. After that, I tried to locate the compiler (file lessc) in my Netbeans IDE (7.4 Beta). After that, I got the following Error-Message:

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm not sure if Less compiler can work without NodeJS. So I would do following:

- install NodeJS (nodejs.org)
- install less  compiler using npm

  npm install -g less
- then NetBeans should find it, if not, you need to specify path to lessc.cmd, e.g.

  C:\Users\lada\AppData\Roaming\npm\lessc.cmd
- to find where is your lessc.cmd, run following in command line

  where lessc.cmd

The lessc (without cmd) is for Linux and Mac OSX

Comment: Just to say, you prob have to run as sudo in Mac OS so:
sudo npm install -g less

Answer (score 9):

I downloaded lessc from here:

https://github.com/duncansmart/less.js-windows

unzipped the zip-file and copied all files to C:\bin\lessc but you can copy it anywhere you like.

Then just point Netbeans to that folder and lessc.cmd and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

**Try:**

1. Install nodejs
2. Install less in nodejs "cmd: npm install less"
3. less path netbeans: C:\nodejs\node_modules.bin\lessc.cmd